# extract portion of string using sql depending on content

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have data in column `fullname`

Examples :

```
Mr Robert                          
Mr Frnk Perk                       
Mr Grenille Ta                    
Mrs Fraes Kin                        
Isoel Newto                          
Mr Iin McLen                          
Keh Farringn                        
Mr Sepen Taor                       
Peer Snce                            
Mr Plip Luon                        
Mr Andew Macie                                                     
Mr Timhy Waers                      
Mrs Juiet Wriht                       
Kaye Ashwth                           
Dr Meryn Wiseman
```

How do I extract only title `'Mr','Mrs','Dr',' '` etc. Should be as it is if there is not title for particular name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring method with a decode.

```
DECODE (TRIM(SUBSTR(string,0 ,3)), 'Mr', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Mrs','Dr', 'Dr', '')
```

Assuming you're using oracle. Please specify which DB you're using.

Comment: Thank you @vargan for you answer ! can you please  write full query so i can get output as Mr,Mrs,Miss,Dr etc. m using sqlserver

Comment: I'm not an expert of SQL server, I think you have to wait for someone more expert

Answer (score 0):

Here's some little snippet using regular expressions:

REGEXP_SUBSTR(p.full_name, '^\S+',1,1) - this extracts the entire text from the start to the first whitespace.

REGEXP_LIKE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p.full_name, '^\S+',1,1), '^(Mr|Mrs|Dr)$') - this checks if the extracted text is Mr or Mrs or Dr.

```
WITH people AS 
(
SELECT
  DECODE(LEVEL
    ,1, 'Mr Robert' 
    ,2, 'Mr Frnk Perk'
    ,3, 'Mr Grenille Ta'
    ,4, 'Mrs Fraes Kin'
    ,5, 'Isoel Newto'                          
    ,6, 'Mr Iin McLen'                          
    ,7, 'Keh Farringn'                        
    ,8, 'Mr Sepen Taor'                       
    ,9, 'Peer Snce'                            
    ,10, 'Mr Plip Luon'                        
    ,11, 'Mr Andew Macie'                                                     
    ,12, 'Mr Timhy Waers'                      
    ,13, 'Mrs Juiet Wriht'                       
    ,14, 'Kaye Ashwth'                           
    ,15, 'Dr Meryn Wiseman'
  ) AS full_name
FROM
  dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 16
)
SELECT
  p.full_name
  ,CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p.full_name, '^\S+',1,1), '^(Mr|Mrs|Dr)$') THEN
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(p.full_name, '^\S+',1,1)
    ELSE
      ' '
  END AS title
FROM
  people p
```

Gives the following result:

```
FULL_NAME        |  TITLE
------------------------
Mr Robert        |  Mr
Mr Frnk Perk     |  Mr
Mr Grenille Ta   |  Mr
Mrs Fraes Kin    |  Mrs
Isoel Newto      |  
Mr Iin McLen     |  Mr
Keh Farringn     |  
Mr Sepen Taor    |  Mr
Peer Snce        |  
Mr Plip Luon     |  Mr
Mr Andew Macie   |  Mr
Mr Timhy Waers   |  Mr
Mrs Juiet Wriht  |  Mrs
Kaye Ashwth      |  
Dr Meryn Wiseman |  Dr
```